# Installing MacTeX

Tags: installing

I've been trying to install the MacTeX package (MacTeX.mpkg), but each time I download it and attempt to install, I receive this error message, and the installation halts: com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1

I am using a modern iMac running OS X 10.6.5. Any suggestions would be great appreciated.

Comment: Google seems to indicate it might be a bad package.  Is this a recent build?

Comment: Yes - I downloaded it directly from the MacTeX homepage: http://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: And this has occurred each of the three times I have downloaded it from that link. Others must be having the same issue.

Comment: It looks like I've resolved the issue - I needed to use a difference .zip expander (stuffit expander) to unpack MacTeX.mpkg. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Adam. Based on the last comment and the lack of anyone else seeing this (for example, on the MacTeX mailing list), I'm closing this as a 'local' issue.